# cannot open load file org2blog-autoloads

Tags: org-mode, init-file

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 lts and emacs 24.3.1

The error I get is

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/guy/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: org2blog-autoloads
```

I set the in comment while it is not working.
The file exists and I have user privileges.

org2blog portion of my .emacs file :

```el
;; org2blog
;; org2blog dependencies
(add-to-list 'load-path '“~/.emacs.d/elisps/metaweblog/”)
(add-to-list 'load-path '“~/.emacs.d/elpa/xml-rpc-1.6.8/”)
(add-to-list 'load-path '“~/.emacs.d/elpa/org2blog-0.5/”)
;(require 'org2blog-autoloads)

;; org2blog setup blog
(setq org2blog/wp-blog-alist
      '(("steptoharmony"
         :url "http://steptoharmony.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php"
         :username "guybon"
         :default-title "Hello World"
         :default-categories ()
         :tags-as-categories nil)
       )
)
```

location of file :

```
.emacs.d/elpa/org2blog-0.5:
metaweblog.el org2blog-autoloads.el org2blog-autoloads.elc org2blog.elc org2blog-pkg.elc
metaweblog.elc org2blog-autoloads.el~ org2blog.el org2blog-pkg.el
```

Starting emacs with '--debug-init' gives this

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "org2blog-autoloads")
require(org2blog-autoloads)
eval-buffer(# nil "/home/guy/.emacs" nil t) ; Reading at buffer position 1169
load-with-code-conversion("/home/guy/.emacs" "/home/guy/.emacs" t t)
load("~/.emacs" t t)
```

load-path = 
    ("/home/guy/.emacs.d/elpa/org2blog-0.5" "/home/guy/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20150223" "/home/guy/.emacs.d/elpa/xml-rpc-1.6.8" “~/.emacs.d/elpa/org2blog-0.5/” “~/.emacs.d/elpa/xml-rpc-1.6.8/” “~/.emacs.d/elisps/metaweblog/” "/etc/emacs24" "/etc/emacs" "/usr/local/share/emacs/24.3/site-lisp" "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp" "/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/git" "/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/dictionaries-common" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/site-lisp" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/site-lisp/git" "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/vc" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/url" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/textmodes" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/progmodes" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/play" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/org" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/nxml" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/net" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/mh-e" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/mail" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/language" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/international" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/gnus" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/eshell" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/erc" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/emulation" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/emacs-lisp" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/cedet" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/calendar" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/calc" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/obsolete" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/leim")

Comment: What is the value of your `load-path`?